# End Process vs End Process Tree

Tags: windows, linux

What is the primary difference between the two? I always see this in the right click menu in windows. What happens if you end a process that is relied upon by another process? Is there a way to "kill" a process tree in linux or is the technology different?

Answer (score 11):

When you start a process, many of them can be used to either call additional instances or separate processes.

[image]

These are called child processes, additionally each child can then call child processes (Making the original process a grandparent, and each of these new processes as grand child processes).

If you kill the parent process, it should also kill the children / grandchildren in the tree.

It is possible to call processes and not be officially in the tree though. This is a rough concept.

Also, [Linux can kill trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392022/best-way-to-kill-all-child-processes) but it is generally not as straight forward as right clicking a process in the activity monitor.

Comment: Regarding killing, you can have orphan processes too.

Comment: Yep, I tried not to over complicate it for the sake of the answer... Although its a good point.

Comment: will "If you kill the parent process, it should also kill the children / grandchildren in the tree." require "end process" or "end process tree?" Also how is this done in linux?